# Retrieving Product tag to use in query in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce

I'm trying to query posts with same tag as my product tag.
I can print my tag before my query (see first line of code), it works, but then inside the query it all goes wrong.

```
<?php echo $product->get_tags(); ?>
<?php
 $producttags = get_tags();
 if ($producttags) {
foreach($producttags as $tag) {
    $tag = $tag->slug;  break;
}
query_posts('tag='.$tag.'&posts_per_page=-1');
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="actucontent">
  <h3>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </h3>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```

Any idea? Problem is, I have no clue how to call `$product->get_tags()` inside my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_tags() is a member of WP_Post, whereas $product is type WC_Product_Simple